# Global and local recursive functions in lua

Tags: variables, recursion, lua, scripting-language

I am very new to lua and I would like to understand following behaviour.

When I try to run following recursion function:

```
local func = function ( n )
  if n == 1 then return 1
  else return n * func( n - 1 )
  end
end

print( func( 5 ) )
```

The program will fail with error:

```
lua: main.lua:16: attempt to call a nil value (global 'func')
stack traceback:
main.lua:16: in local 'func'
main.lua:38: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

which is ok, since according to the [explanation](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.2.html), local version of *func* variable is not known yet so it tries to call the global one. But when I delete *local* keyword, following code works correctly?

```
func = function ( n )
  if n == 1 then return 1
  else return n * func( n - 1 )
  end
end

print( func( 5 ) )
```

Program prints 120 as result, but global *func* was never initialized or used before. How is it possible, that this does not throw error as well? Isn't the second example referencing to global *func* as it does in the first one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Isn't the second example referencing to global func as it does in the first one?

It is :)

You see, it doesn't matter if value exists or not when you compile new function. It doesn't check the value stored in the `func` variable, instead it will look it up every time the call is made. The only important thing is variable's visibility. If the variable isn't visible in local scope, then it's considered global, and will be looked up in the global environment table. For more details see Lua manual, chapter [3.5 – Visibility Rules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.5)

The first example didn't work because `local func` variable isn't visible until complete expression is calculated. That's why the first example breaks, trying to call missing global variable.

If you want that func to be local, declare the variable, and *then* assign it. Like:

```
local func
func = function ( n )
  if n == 1 then return 1
  else return n * func( n - 1 )
  end
end

print( func( 5 ) )
```

Probably it will be easier to use Lua's syntactic sugar for this cases:

```
local function func( n )
  if n == 1 then return 1
  else return n * func( n - 1 )
  end
end

print( func( 5 ) )
```

It will be translated exactly to the same sequence of declaring variable, and then assigning it.

This time the `func` variable will be visible to new `function(n)`, so it will read value to call from that specific upvalue.

Note that it's still possible to "break" the function by assigning something different into `func` variable later. Functions (as any other value) in Lua doesn't have names, only variables do. So calls to functions isn't hardcompiled, the function value to call is always fetched from the variable, before each call.

Comment: It is clear to me now. So when calling local func(), the inner func() is still referencing the global (uninitialized) version of it even though at the time when the call was made, local func() had already existed. Just verified this "visually" by declaring global func() together with local version while printing some helper messages within them. Didn't think of it in that way initially. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Vlad [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210132/2226988) the question well. A couple points about the question for clarity:

1. Functions are values so "global function" as in the title doesn't sense by itself without the context of the question.
2. Variable binding is the process by which the compiler maps an identifier in the code to a variable. Questions about variable binding typically come up regarding recursive functions but the binding rules are simpler and more general. They don't have anything to do with recursion, function *definitions* or even local vs global. Nonetheless, the syntactic sugar for function definition *statements* can confuse the issue.

For example:

```
local x = x + 1
```

`x` in the expression is not the `x` being created. Which variable it is depends on any code above. It could be a local declared in a statement block or as a function parameter. Such a declaration could be in the same block or function definition or *above* in an outer one. Global is just the fallback.

Obviously, if `local` wasn't used in the example above, the same name would be bound to same variable.

```
 y = y + 1
```

Both `y` names are the same variable but, as above, which variable is determined by other code.

This function definition statement is similar:

```
 function f() end
```

If a local `f` is in scope then that is the variable the compiler binds "f" to, otherwise "f" in the global environment.